# number limit of the request POST type signed call instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Recently I had a problem with a number limit of the request POST (delete comments) with API Instagram, it is only 15 per hour. I moved my application to signed calls I checked the option Enforce signed requests.
I generated a new access token, but the number limit is always 15 per hour but in  documentation it said 60 per hour if the application is type signed calls.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to have your app approved for POST requests, enabling the limit to go up to 60 per hour?